# These compiler options into a CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, cmake

I am trying to create a CMakeLists.txt out of the inline compile options-

```
g++ -Wall -I/usr/include/cppconn -o testapp tester.cpp -L/usr/lib -lmysqlcppconn
```

I expected the following to work

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-Wall")

project(testapp)

find_package(PCL 1.4 REQUIRED)

include_directories(. "/usr/include/cppconn")

link_directories("/usr/lib/" "mysqlcppconn")

add_executable(testapp tester.cpp)
```

But in `make` I get undefined reference errors for the above library's content. Am I misunderstanding `include_directories` and/or `link_directories`?

My tester.cpp includes are this

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql_connection.h>
#include <driver.h>
#include <exception.h>
#include <resultset.h>
#include <statement.h>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need to actually link against the library, `link_directories()` only specifies multiple directories. 
You need to add

```
target_link_libraries(testapp mysqlcppconn)
```

after `add_executable()`

also you should be able to skip the `link_directories()` completely `/usr/lib` is usually in the library search path by default.

Comment: Thanks, making more sense now

Answer (score 3):

You aren't actually specifying the libraries you want to link to anywhere, see the documentation for [link_directories](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:link_directories) (all it takes is a list of directories). You'll want to look into [target_link_libraries](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:target_link_libraries). You may also want to look into [find_library](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:find_library) and ["find modules"](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries) for the preferred way of handling 3rd party libraries with CMake (though you don't necessarily need to).

Comment: @rocketas Added one more link about find modules that might be helpful as well.